# How to handle Bitcoin payments in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, bitcoin

What is the best way to handle Bitcoin payments in a Node.js e-commerce API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many online API service provider as well but for me best option is `bitcore-lib` , Generating a new account and signing transaction can be done offline but to check addresses for payments need to scan bitcoin explorer.

For New account or Address :

```
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
let btc = bitcoin.networks.bitcoin;
let keypair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({network: btc});
var address = keypair.getAddress(); 
var PrivateKey = keypair.toWIF();
```

Sign Transaction

```
const amt = parseInt( value - fee);
const netwk = bitcoin.networks.bitcoin;
const pubKey = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(PrivateKey, netwk);
const txb = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder(netwk);
txb.addInput(tx.txhash, 0)
txb.addOutput(address, amt)
txb.sign(0, pubKey);
const txHex = txb.build().toHex();
```

Comment: What I am really looking for is creating a service like this, more than using it. Nonetheless, if I can't find a deeper answer, I will award the bounty to this one.